# Why we don't need to use string? str and for decimal or int we need to use decimal? price = p?price

Tags: c#, null-conditional-operator

I'm new in c#. I have a confusion in null conditional operator.

in case of string everyone using this line

```
string name = p?.name;
```

but in case of decimal or float

```
decimal? price = p?.price;
int? quantity = p?.count;
```

Comment: The short answer is that reference types, like `string` allow you to assign `null` to them out of the box. Value types like `int` or `decimal` do not - hence the need for **nullable types** like `int?` - see also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/05/27/nullable-types-in-c/ .

Answer (score 2):

actually 'int' and 'decimal' are not reference type.  while 'string' is.  reference type can hold `null` and 'not nullable value', so with string you don't need to use `?` and with `decimal` , `int`, `bool` etc. you will have to use `?` as they are not nullable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types

check the below link, string is reference type and int is value type